# Keeping the selected values in programmatically created DropDownList after button click ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have created a form where I add dropdowns based on form fields from a PDF.

The `namesMapping` variable is a `Dictionary` containing the old values as keys and the new ones as values. To save the values I want to add the current selection to the `Dictionary`. **But the eventlistener is not firing.**

I have read many threads here that say use the `IsPostBack` variable to not update the dropdowns on page reload. But it doesn't seem to work in this case.

It feels like it should be easier to get the selected values from dropdowns. But anyways, **how do I do to save the selected values from the dropdowns so I can get them after I click the button?**

Here is the code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItem[] listItems = new ListItem[4];
        listItems[0] = new ListItem("First Name", "first-name");
        listItems[1] = new ListItem("Last Name", "last-name");
        listItems[2] = new ListItem("Email", "email");
        listItems[3] = new ListItem("Company", "company");

        int counter = 0;
        foreach (PdfField field in fields)
        {
            if (field.GetType() == typeof(PdfTextField))
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                TableCell name = new TableCell
                {
                    Text = field.Name
                };
                tr.Cells.Add(name);
                TableCell options = new TableCell();

                DropDownList dropdown = new DropDownList();
                dropdown.ID = field.Name;
                for (int i = 0; i < listItems.Length; i++)
                {
                    dropdown.Items.Add(listItems[i]);
                }
                dropdown.SelectedIndexChanged += Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged;

                options.Controls.Add(dropdown);
                tr.Cells.Add(options);
                Table1.Rows.Add(tr);

                //If page loads for the first time, set the mapping to the default selected values
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    namesMapping.Add(field.Name, dropdown.SelectedValue);
                }
            }
        }

    private void Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList dropDown = (DropDownList) sender;
        namesMapping[dropDown.ID] = dropDown.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Thanks for answers.

**Edit**

I moved the code where the dropdowns are created to be within `if(!IsPostBack)` so they are not recreated when reloading the page. I save all the dropdowns in a `Dictionary`, but they still show the first value as the selected when selecting another in the dropdown.

Here is the code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            doc = new PdfDocument(pdfFileName);

            namesMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            ddlMappings = new Dictionary<string, DropDownList>();

            //Get all fields
            fields = doc.Fields;

            //Create the dropdown lists
            dropdownLists = new List<DropDownList>();

            ListItem[] listItems = new ListItem[4];
            listItems[0] = new ListItem("First Name", "first-name");
            listItems[1] = new ListItem("Last Name", "last-name");
            listItems[2] = new ListItem("Email", "email");
            listItems[3] = new ListItem("Company", "company");

            int counter = 0;
            foreach (PdfField field in fields)
            {
                //Only display the text fields
                if (field.GetType() == typeof(PdfTextField))
                {
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                    //Add the field name
                    TableCell name = new TableCell
                    {
                        Text = field.Name
                    };
                    tr.Cells.Add(name);
                    //Add the options to select from
                    TableCell options = new TableCell();

                    DropDownList dropdown = new DropDownList();
                    dropdown.ID = field.Name;

                    //Populate the dropdown
                    for (int i = 0; i < listItems.Length; i++)
                    {
                        dropdown.Items.Add(listItems[i]);
                    }

                    dropdown.AutoPostBack = true;
                    dropdown.SelectedIndexChanged += Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged;

                    options.Controls.Add(dropdown);
                    tr.Cells.Add(options);
                    //Add row to table
                    Table1.Rows.Add(tr);

                    //If page loads for the first time, set the mapping to the default selected values
                    namesMapping.Add(field.Name, dropdown.SelectedValue);
                    ddlMappings.Add(field.Name, dropdown);
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            foreach (PdfField field in fields)
            {
                //Only display the text fields
                if (field.GetType() == typeof(PdfTextField))
                {
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                    //Add the field name
                    TableCell name = new TableCell
                    {
                        Text = field.Name
                    };
                    tr.Cells.Add(name);
                    //Add the options to select from
                    TableCell options = new TableCell();

                    DropDownList dropdown = ddlMappings[field.Name];
                    dropdown.SelectedIndexChanged += Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged;

                    options.Controls.Add(dropdown);
                    tr.Cells.Add(options);
                    //Add row to table
                    Table1.Rows.Add(tr);

                }
            }

        }

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            foreach(var ddl in ddlMappings)
            {
                ddl.Value.SelectedValue = namesMapping[ddl.Key];
            }
        }
    }


    private void Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList dropDown = (DropDownList) sender;
        namesMapping[dropDown.ID] = dropDown.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or the SelectedIndexChanged event is not firing at all??

Comment: Just found out that it does not fire until I press the button unless I add `AutoPostBack = true`, but then it fires after the page reloads and I loose the selected values.

Comment: have you tried putting all your code inside if(!Page.IsPostBack)??? You are losing your value because your Dropdownlist is binding each time you change the selection.try putting all your code inside the if block and see.

Comment: If I do that, the Table is empty and there is no dropdowns.

Comment: Manage a `Dictionary<string, DropDownList>` that maps DropDownList IDs to the objects themselves and fill it along with `namesMapping`. Then at the end of `Page_Load`, add a loop that runs over all objects in the dictionary and sets their SelectedValue property according to the correct entry in the `namesMapping` dictionary. This will allow you to retain the up to date state of the list selections between page reloads.

Comment: The problem is that the `namesMapping` gets updated after the page has reloaded so the dropdowns are back to default and thus the mapping will always be to "First Name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem after reading this article:

[Maintain The State Of Dynamic Added User Control On Each PostBack](http://www.gurujipoint.com/2017/07/maintain-state-of-dynamic-added-user.html)

I used the `ViewState` to save ID of the dropdowns to be able to recreate them on Postback. Here is the code:

```
public Dictionary<Guid, string> DropdownLists
{
    get { return ViewState["MyDropdowns"] != null
            ? (Dictionary<Guid, string>)ViewState["MyDropdowns"] : new Dictionary<Guid, string>(); }
    set { ViewState["MyDropdowns"] = value; }
}

public Dictionary<Guid, string> DropdownNames
{
    get { return ViewState["DropdownNames"] != null
    ? (Dictionary<Guid, string>)ViewState["DropdownNames"] : new Dictionary<Guid, string>(); }
    set { ViewState["DropdownNames"] = value; }
}
```

First I added these two class variables which saves their values in the `ViewState`. Then the when the page loads the first time the method `CreateForm()` is called which creates all the dropdowns based on the fields in the PDF file. When the page is loaded on postback the dropdowns are created based on the values stored in the `ViewState`. The code is the following:

```
protected void Page_Load()
{

    //Load the file
    doc = new PdfDocument(pdfFileName);

    //Get all fields
    fields = doc.Fields;

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        CreateForm();
    }
    else
    {
        RecreateForm();
    }
}

private void CreateForm()
{

    Dictionary<Guid, string> tempList = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();
    Dictionary<Guid, string> tempNames = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();

    foreach (PdfField field in fields)
    {
        //Only display the text fields
        if (field.GetType() == typeof(PdfTextField))
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            TableCell name = new TableCell
            {
                Text = field.Name
            };
            tr.Cells.Add(name);
            TableCell options = new TableCell();

            DropdownList dropdown = (DropdownList)LoadControl("~/DropdownList.ascx");

            Guid nextKey = Guid.NewGuid();
            tempList[nextKey] = "dropdown" + nextKey.ToString().Replace('-', '_');
            dropdown.ID = tempList[nextKey];

            tempNames[nextKey] = field.Name;

            options.Controls.Add(dropdown);
            tr.Cells.Add(options);

            Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
    }
    DropdownLists = tempList;
    DropdownNames = tempNames;
}

private void RecreateForm()
{
    foreach (var item in DropdownLists)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell name = new TableCell
        {
            Text = DropdownNames[item.Key]
        };
        tr.Cells.Add(name);
        TableCell options = new TableCell();

        DropdownList dropdown = (DropdownList)LoadControl("~/DropdownList.ascx");

        dropdown.ID = DropdownLists[item.Key];

        options.Controls.Add(dropdown);
        tr.Cells.Add(options);

        Table1.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps anyone out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're databinding in `Page_Load`, you're also resetting the SelectedItem.

You should add the  binding code that exists in `Page_Load` inside an `if(!IsPostBack)` block.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{

    // Your binding code here ...

}
```

Here is sample of code for you to do the binding...

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</form>
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            Bind();
        }


    }


protected void Bind() {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string));
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Path", typeof(string));


        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "1";
        dr["Path"] = Server.MapPath("ProDinner1.pdf");

        DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
        dr2["Name"] = "2";
        dr2["Path"] = Server.MapPath("ProDinner2.pdf");

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dt.Rows.Add(dr2);

        DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Path";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        Session["path"] = path;
        Response.Write("<script language=javascript>window.open('show.aspx')</script>");



    }
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still doesn't work. The dropdowns keeps having the same value.